# ODE events where value is not part of the state

Tags: matlab, events, ode

I'm currently working on a simple hybrid dynamical system with discrete state jumps. For that, I'm using ODE events. The problem is that my 'value's' (that which will cross zero) are not directly related to the state of the dynamical system. I'm not able to express these variables alongside the proper state (e.g. position + velocity of angles).

Currently, I'm using global variables but it seems that MATLAB does not decrease the step-size when the 'value' crosses zero. I assume this is because the value is not part of the state. Here is the code for the events;

```
function [value, isterminal,direction] = leg_events(t,x)
global isSwingL isSwingR frcLegL frcLegR posFooL posFooR frcComL frcComR
value = [];
isterminal = [];
direction = [];
if isSwingL
    value = [value; posFooL(2)];
    isterminal = [isterminal; 1];
    direction = [direction; -1];
else
    value = [value; frcComL(2)];
    isterminal = [isterminal; 1];
    direction = [direction; -1];
end
if isSwingR
    value = [value; posFooR(2)];
    isterminal = [isterminal; 1];
    direction = [direction; -1];
else
    value = [value; frcComR(2)];
    isterminal = [isterminal; 1];
    direction = [direction; -1];
end     
end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Please let me know.
The model is implemented in Simulink which doe seem to be able to deal with this kind of thing but I need it specifically in code for optimization purposes.

I've also considered changing the 'MaxStep' but this makes the simulation unnecessary slow and unusable for the optimization.

[some context]: In concrete terms, the problem is that if I print the value of the event function during operation, the values occur as such ->

```
[0.2 0.12 0.4 -0.2 detected crossing]
```

Where the event is detected at -0.2. The state at this instance in time is taken to continue with the state but the system has clearly been progressed further making the subsequent dynamics of the system nonsense. I would have expected this ->

```
[0.2 0.12 0.4 0.1 0.01 0.001 -0.001 detected crossing]
```

which is what happens when the 'value' in the event function is part of the input arguments of the event function itself. Is it possible to ensure that the step size gets decreased when a 'value' that is not based on an input variable appears to cross the zero line?
Hope this helps

Comment: The ODE solver computes an internal step and its "dense output" interpolation. At this point the derivatives function is no more called for this segment. Then the sign sequence of the event function is compared for both ends of the segments and probably also for some internal points, using solver-internal interpolation for the states. On sign change in a component, some bracketing solver (Dekker, Brent) is applied to the composition of interpolation and event function. There is no feed-back to solver-external procedures at this point. Please describe your situation with more context.

Comment: I have updated it. Please see the original post. From your comment, it appears to me that this is not a possibility?